# Encrypting data partition following Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019

Tags: partitioning, encryption

The following guide shows how to encrypt /boot and the system partition:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019

It doesn't mention anything in case one wants to have a data partition as well.

Would the steps for encrypting a data partition in addition to the OS partition be the same as the steps for encrypting the OS partition? And the keys for the data partition will also be stored in /boot so that a password is entered only once on boot?

Comment: Full disk implies to me all partitions on the disk, which includes your data partition if setup at the same time, and on same disk (even if your /home is on a separate partition), ie. full disk means any partitions setup on that *physical* disk.

Comment: Your comment doesn't answer the question. And why was the question downvoted - it's a legitimate question - if someone has a different point of view, please share it.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? or have you succeded in doing it?

Comment: I did, but it was too complicated. I just use Ubuntu 20 default encryption for the whole system drive and then VeraCrypt for any additional drives I have.